# Calculating the mean of elements in a list in Scala

Tags: scala, list, mean

I'm trying to write a method that calculates the mean of the elements in a given `List` in Scala. Here's my code:

```
def meanElements(list: List[Float]): Float = {
  list match {
    case x :: tail => (x + meanElements(tail))/(list.length)
    case Nil => 0
  }
}
```

When I call `meanElements(List(10,12,14)))`, the result I get is different than 12. Can someone help?

Comment: Please don't tag `scala` questions with `Java` they're completely different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is not correct, it should be:

```
case x :: tail => (x + meanElements(tail) * tail.length) / list.length
```

But this implementation is performing a lot of divisions and multiplications.
It would be better to split the computation of the mean to two steps,
calculating the sum first,
and then dividing by `list.length`.

That is, something more like this:

```
def meanElements(list: List[Float]): Float = sum(list) / list.length
```

Where `sum` is a helper function you have to implement.
If you don't want to expose its implementation,
then you can define it in the body of `meanElements`.
(Or as [@ph88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4484857/ph88) pointed out,
it could be as simple as `list.reduce(_ + _)`.)

Comment: How can I do the computation in 2 steps? I replaced the line of the match with case x :: tail => x + meanElements(tail) so that I can have the sum, but how do I print out the mean at the end? Thanks.

Comment: You can sum using `reduce`.  i.e. it can be as simple as `def meanElements(list: List[Float]): Float = list.reduce(_ + _) / list.length`

Comment: @PH88 good one, thanks. In any case, I guess OP wants to practice recursion.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do it using inbuilt functions:

```
scala> def mean(list:List[Int]):Int = 
     | if(list.isEmpty) 0 else list.sum/list.size
mean: (list: List[Int])Int

scala> mean(List(10,12,14))
res1: Int = 12

scala>
```

Comment: You may wish to `list.sum.toDouble/list.size` since the mean might not be an integer